# Vue.js - redirecting user not authenticated to specific page, different from login

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For now I have this piece of code

```
import addToast from '@/utils/toast-queue';
import routes from './routes';
import App from './app';
import './assets/styles/global.scss';
import { jsonRequest } from './utils/requests';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({ routes });

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    const userInfo = await jsonRequest('GET', '/user/info');
    const notAuthenticated = userInfo.status !== 200;

    if (to.name !== 'login' && notAuthenticated) {
        if (to.name === 'survey') {
            next({ name: 'survey' });
        } else {
            addToast('Please login', { type: 'error' });
            next({ name: 'login' });
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

/* eslint-disable-next-line no-new */
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

When a GET request comes from `/user/info` to the path `/public/form` I would like an user not authenticated to be redirected to the page displaying the form. How can I achieve this in vue.js?
I have declared the route in `route.js` file like this

```
{
   path: '/public/form',
   name: 'form',
   component: () => import('./views/form'),
}
```

I updated the `beforeEach()` like this

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    const userInfo = await jsonRequest('GET', '/user/info');
    const notAuthenticated = userInfo.status !== 200;

    if (to.name !== 'login' && notAuthenticated) {
        if (to.name === 'form') {
            next({ name: 'form' });
        } else {
            addToast('Please login', { type: 'error' });
            next({ name: 'login' });
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

but it seems not working

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards), you should use

```
return { name: 'Login' };
```

or

```
return '/login';
```

instead of

```
next({ name: 'login' });
```

The same for form.

Comment: So I should remove next. But it doesn't work for me as well

Comment: Did you console.log() userInfo.status then inside the different conditions to be sure they are executed?

Comment: Looks like the first "if" could be:
if (to.name !== 'login' && to.name !== 'form' && notAuthenticated) {
then you redirect to login page

Comment: Yeah, I resolved. It was a problem related to where to write the condition to check for ```survey``` path. I needed to do first this and then check for authentication